# SQL Server GRANT EXECUTE ON TRIGGER TO USER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, database-trigger

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGER_UPDATE_MODIFIED]
   ON  [dbo].[MY_TABLE]   
   AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    UPDATE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] SET [DATE_MODIFIED] = GETDATE(), [USER_MODIFIED] = CASE WHEN UPDATE ([USER_MODIFIED]) THEN i.[USER_MODIFIED] ELSE RIGHT(SUSER_NAME(), 100) END
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE [MY_TABLE].[SOME_FIELD] = i.[SOME_FIELD]

END
```

I need to grant `EXECUTE` permission on this trigger to user `SOME_USER` so I do:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[TRIGGER_UPDATE_MODIFIED] TO [SOME_USER]
    WITH GRANT OPTION
    AS [dbo];
GO
```

And I get following error:

> Cannot find object 'TRIGGER_UPDATE_MODIFIED' because it does not exist or user does not have permission.

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

I have thought about doing this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGER_UPDATE_MODIFIED]
   ON  [dbo].[MY_TABLE]   
   WITH EXECUTE AS 'SOME_USER'
   AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    UPDATE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] SET [DATE_MODIFIED] = GETDATE(), [USER_MODIFIED] = CASE WHEN UPDATE ([USER_MODIFIED]) THEN i.[USER_MODIFIED] ELSE RIGHT(SUSER_NAME(), 100) END
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE [MY_TABLE].[SOME_FIELD] = i.[SOME_FIELD]

END
```

Is that correct (using `WITH EXECUTE AS 'SOME_USER'`)? or maybe using `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`?

What will be the difference?

Comment: I don't think you can grant permissions on triggers. You need to grant the permissions on the table instead.

Comment: Have a look at [this social.MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/edc8acc6-d710-4c0b-bc6c-209912575557/database-trigger-permission?forum=sqlsecurity) - it might help.

Comment: You don't grant permissions on triggers because the whole point of them is that they execute whenever actions happen against the corresponding base table.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ok, and how can I grant the permission on the table to allow trigger be executed by the user "SOME_USER". Could you provide the sql command?

Comment: `GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.table TO user;`

Comment: Why the -1 score? This is a good question, and I've found the answer here

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the comments:
You can't grant permissions on DML triggers. You can only grant permissions to execute the DML statements that will fire the trigger.
In your case, you should grant update permissions on the table to the user:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON [dbo].[MY_TABLE] TO [SOME_USER];
```